# Filter a chunk of rows based on a specific value in another column in R

Tags: r, filter, subset

Example of Constricted Data Table:

[image: img]

I would like to be able to filter out rows of data based on if a particular value exists in another column. The rows I would like to filter out would all have the same "Material" #. In the example I provided, the Material #U83231036 has the value, "ZHLB (ConAgra Semifinished prod)" in one of the two rows in the "Material_Type_Comp" column. I want to be able to extract out the two rows of data related to that Material # because that value exists in the "Material_Type_Comp" column for one of the rows.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a loadable sample of data (not a picture of it), all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to do a `filter` by group

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Material) %>%
   filter("ZHLB (ConAgra Semifinished prod)" %in% Material_Type_Comp)
   #or use any with `==`
   #filter(any(Material_Type_Comp == "ZHLB (ConAgra Semifinished prod)")
```